# C++14 : 2 random generators - one works, the other doesnt

Tags: c++, c++14

Im learning C++, and in my random number gen code, im always getting the same number

```
random_device rd;
mt19937 x{rd()};
uniform_int_distribution<int> ran{1, 100};
cout << ran(x);
```

but srand/rand() works.

```
srand (time(0));
cout << rand()%100;
```

I think that it has to do with time(). But how do i get the first code to work?

Comment: `mt19937 x(rd());`

Comment: Using g++ 8.2 (on linux) I can not reproduce this behavior. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Are you using `MinGW`?

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen What's wrong with uniform initialization for `std::mt19997`? Shouldn't the same constructor be called with `()` and `{}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your problem is with the MinGW g++ compiler, you can define a header that wraps `<random>`, like this:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef MY_NO_FIX_OF_RANDOM_DEVICE
#   ifdef __GNUC__
#       undef   _GLIBCXX_USE_RANDOM_TR1
#       define  _GLIBCXX_USE_RANDOM_TR1
#   endif
#endif
#include <random>
```

That's just a modified-for-SO version of [a header in the Wrapped stdlib library](https://github.com/alf-p-steinbach/Wrapped-stdlib/blob/master/source/fix/gcc_random_device.hpp).

I would recommend to use a forced include (command line option) of this fix, or just defining `_GLIBCXX_USE_RANDOM_TR1` in the command line.

---

By inspecting the source code of my MinGW g++ 7.3.0, files `<random.h>` and `random.cc`, it appears that the approach works on most PCs because (with that compiler) `_GLIBCXX_USE_RANDOM_TR1` selects number generation via the `rdrand` instruction, if available, and else via the `"/dev/urandom"` *nix world device, if available.

So, criteria for “works”:

- the processor supports the `rdrand` instruction, *or*
- `fopen` succeeds in opening `"/dev/urandom"`.

According to the [Wikipedia article about `rdrand`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand)

> **”** AMD added support for the instruction in June 2015.

... so this approach may fail on a Windows PC (no `"/dev/urandom"`) with AMD processor produced before that time (no `rdrand` instruction).

---

Technical details:

With `_GLIBCXX_USE_RANDOM_TR1` defined the `random_device` default constructor calls the following function with argument `"default"`:

```
  void
  random_device::_M_init(const std::string& token)
  {
    const char *fname = token.c_str();

    if (token == "default")
      {
#if (defined __i386__ || defined __x86_64__) && defined _GLIBCXX_X86_RDRAND
    unsigned int eax, ebx, ecx, edx;
    // Check availability of cpuid and, for now at least, also the
    // CPU signature for Intel's
    if (__get_cpuid_max(0, &ebx) > 0 && ebx == signature_INTEL_ebx)
      {
        __cpuid(1, eax, ebx, ecx, edx);
        if (ecx & bit_RDRND)
          {
        _M_file = nullptr;
        return;
          }
      }
#endif

    fname = "/dev/urandom";
      }
    else if (token != "/dev/urandom" && token != "/dev/random")
    fail:
      std::__throw_runtime_error(__N("random_device::"
                     "random_device(const std::string&)"));

    _M_file = static_cast<void*>(std::fopen(fname, "rb"));
    if (!_M_file)
      goto fail;
  }
```

If `__cpuid` reports that the processor supports the `rdrand` instruction then this causes the `_M_file` member to be zeroed, which in turn causes the number generation code to use the `rdrand` instruction.

And otherwise, this code attempts to open the *nix random device, and if that fails then it and hence the `random_device` construction fails with an exception.

Comment: Could you please explain *why* does it help? Is it a workaround for a bug in MinGW? What is defined under `_GLIBCXX_USE_RANDOM_TR1` and why do we meddle in compiler specific macros?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: It may take some time. Quick googling only led to earlier postings by myself on SO and Reddit. But I would guess that the "random" seed one gets is not sufficiently random that the libstd++ devs felt it was right to make that the default behavior. Checking now...

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf  Yes, im using MinGW. I have used just #define  _GLIBCXX_USE_RANDOM_TR1 and it now works. Thanks.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: I updated the answer with the results of my investigation.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Great answer, thank you! I hope to see this question used as dupe target in the future :) (It would probably require an edit to question first)